# How to make this regex replace work on all characters, not just the first?

Tags: javascript, regex

I’m trying to replace all spaces within a string with hyphens. I tried this:

```js
h3Text.replace(/\s/, '-');
```

But it only replaces the first instance of a space and not the ones after it. What is the regex to make it replace *all* empty spaces?

Comment: Since you only mentioned replacing spaces and not whitespace, you should know that `\s` will replace all 'whitespace', including newlines, carriage returns, tabs. Maybe that is what you wanted, but just letting you know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

```
h3Text.replace(/\s/g, '-');
```

the **g** flag is key here. it means global replace, ie replace all

Comment: Correct. This makes the regex do a 'g'lobal match, ie, replacing all occurrences instead of just the first.