# .replace() Is Not Replacing All Characters (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have been trying to replace all underscores with an apostrophe. It works with the first underscore, but never with the second. I tried figuring it out but was unable. If you have a solution, please help me.

```js
function strReplace() {
  var myStr = 'quick_brown_fox';
  myStr = myStr.replace(/_/, "’");

  // Insert modified string in paragraph
  document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = myStr;
}
```

```html
<p id="myText">quick_brown_fox</p>
<button type="button" onclick="strReplace();">Replace</button>
```

Output:

> quick’brown_fox

Wanted Output:

> quick’brown’fox

Comment: _“I tried figuring it out but was unable”_ — did you try reading the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to make this regex replace work on all characters, not just the first?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5864082/4642212).

Comment: in hind sight I should have probably gone to the official java script website...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a global search flag to your regex to match all occurrences of `_`

```js
function strReplace() {
  var myStr = 'quick_brown_fox';
  myStr = myStr.replace(/_/g, "’");

  // Insert modified string in paragraph
  document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = myStr;
}
```

```html
<p id="myText">quick_brown_fox</p>
<button type="button" onclick="strReplace();">Replace</button>
```